# Otimização de consulta que soma valores conforme uma cláusula

Tags: sql, query, postgresql

Tenho uma consulta que devo trazer duas colunas, sendo que uma das colunas retornará o valor de uma coluna, mais o somatório de outra coluna respeitando a cláusula `where` para somar os valores.

Cheguei a encontrar o resultado que me serve da seguinte maneira:

```
select
    a.entcodent as codent,
    a.asscodfpg as codfpg,
    a.asscodass as codigo,
    a.assmatass as matricula,
    a.assnomass as nome,
    a.asslogema as email,
    case a.assnivass when '0' then 'P' when '1' then 'O' END as nivel,
    f.fpgrazsoc as fonte_pagadora,
    a.asslimcre - coalesce( (select sum(movvalpri) as consumo from car550 inner join car400 on car550.lojcodloj = car400.lojcodloj and car550.entcodent = car400.entcodent and (car400.vintipvin = 1 or car400.lojcodloj = 9020) where car550.entcodent = a.entcodent and car550.asscodass = a.asscodass and car550.mes_vencimento = f.fpgultmes +1 and car550.movestor = '0' and car550.movvalpri < 0) , 0) as limite,
        (select sum(movvalpri) as consumo from car550 inner join car400 on car550.lojcodloj = car400.lojcodloj and car550.entcodent = car400.entcodent and car400.vintipvin = 1 where car550.entcodent = a.entcodent and car550.asscodass = a.asscodass and car550.mes_vencimento = f.fpgultmes +1 and car550.movestor = '0' and car550.movvalpri > 0) as consumo,
        (a.asslimcre - (select sum(movvalpri) as consumo from car550 inner join car400 on car550.lojcodloj = car400.lojcodloj and car550.entcodent = car400.entcodent and (car400.vintipvin = 1 or car400.lojcodloj = 9020) where car550.entcodent = a.entcodent and car550.asscodass = a.asscodass and car550.mes_vencimento = f.fpgultmes +1 and car550.movestor = '0')) as saldo,
        coalesce(
                (select max(movdatcom) from car550 where entcodent = a.entcodent and asscodass = a.asscodass), 
                (select max(liqdatcom) from car10001 where entcodent = a.entcodent and liqcodass = a.asscodass)
    ) as data_ultima_autorizacao,
    f.fpgrazsoc as nomfpg,
    coalesce(t.cartao_numero, c.carnumcar) as numeroCartao,
    case a.asssitass when '0' then 'L' when '' then 'L' else 'B' END as status
from
    car100 as a
    inner join fonte_pg as f on f.fpgcodfpg = a.asscodfpg and f.fpgcodent = a.entcodent
    left join car500 as c on c.entcodent = a.entcodent and c.asscodass = a.asscodass and a.assultvia = c.carviacar
    left join tbz_cartao as t on t.entidade_codigo = a.entcodent and t.associado_codigo = a.asscodass and t.cartao_via = a.assultvia and t.cartao_tipo = '0'
where
    f.fpgcodent = a.entcodent and
    f.fpgcodfpg = a.asscodfpg
```

Como podem ver, nas colunas apelidadas de limite, consumo e saldo, eu montei o resultado conforme uma cláusula (usando uma outra consulta).

Entretanto, quando busco vários registros, a consulta se torna um tanto lenta.
Alguém teria uma dica de leitura para uma outra abordagem em que possa otimizar o que preciso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Tente algo mais ou menos assim:

```
   WITH querys AS (
                            SELECT COALESCE(sum(movvalpri), 0) AS limite, null AS consumo, null AS saldo, null AS data_ultima_autorizacao
                             FROM car550
                             INNER JOIN car400 ON car550.lojcodloj = car400.lojcodloj
                             AND car550.entcodent = car400.entcodent
                             AND (car400.vintipvin = 1
                                  OR car400.lojcodloj = 9020)
                             WHERE car550.entcodent = a.entcodent
                               AND car550.asscodass = a.asscodass
                               AND car550.mes_vencimento = f.fpgultmes +1
                               AND car550.movestor = '0'
                               AND car550.movvalpri < 0
                               UNION ALL

                               SELECT null AS limite, COALESCE(sum(movvalpri), 0) AS consumo, null AS saldo, null AS data_ultima_autorizacao
                                FROM car550
                                INNER JOIN car400 ON car550.lojcodloj = car400.lojcodloj
                                AND car550.entcodent = car400.entcodent
                                AND car400.vintipvin = 1
                                WHERE car550.entcodent = a.entcodent
                                AND car550.asscodass = a.asscodass
                                AND car550.mes_vencimento = f.fpgultmes +1
                                AND car550.movestor = '0'
                                AND car550.movvalpri > 0
                                UNION ALL

                                SELECT null AS limite, null AS consumo, COALESCE(sum(movvalpri, 0)) AS saldo, null AS data_ultima_autorizacao
       FROM car550
       INNER JOIN car400 ON car550.lojcodloj = car400.lojcodloj
       AND car550.entcodent = car400.entcodent
       AND (car400.vintipvin = 1
            OR car400.lojcodloj = 9020)
       WHERE car550.entcodent = a.entcodent
         AND car550.asscodass = a.asscodass
         AND car550.mes_vencimento = f.fpgultmes +1
         AND car550.movestor = '0'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT null AS limite, null AS consumo, null AS saldo, COALESCE((SELECT max(movdatcom)
               FROM car550
               WHERE entcodent = a.entcodent
                 AND asscodass = a.asscodass),
              (SELECT max(liqdatcom)
               FROM car10001
               WHERE entcodent = a.entcodent
                 AND liqcodass = a.asscodass)) AS data_ultima_autorizacao
                 )
    SELECT a.entcodent AS codent,
           a.asscodfpg AS codfpg,
           a.asscodass AS codigo,
           a.assmatass AS matricula,
           a.assnomass AS nome,
           a.asslogema AS email,
           CASE a.assnivass
               WHEN '0' THEN 'P'
               WHEN '1' THEN 'O'
           END AS nivel,
           f.fpgrazsoc AS fonte_pagadora,
           a.asslimcre - querys.limite AS limite,
           querys.consumo,
           (a.asslimcre - saldo) AS saldo,
           data_ultima_autorizacao,
           f.fpgrazsoc AS nomfpg,
           coalesce(t.cartao_numero, c.carnumcar) AS numeroCartao,
           CASE a.asssitass
               WHEN '0' THEN 'L'
               WHEN '' THEN 'L'
               ELSE 'B'
           END AS status
    FROM car100 AS a, querys
    INNER JOIN fonte_pg AS f ON (f.fpgcodfpg = a.asscodfpg AND f.fpgcodent = a.entcodent)
    LEFT JOIN car500 AS c ON (c.entcodent = a.entcodent AND c.asscodass = a.asscodass AND a.assultvia = c.carviacar)
    LEFT JOIN tbz_cartao AS t ON (t.entidade_codigo = a.entcodent AND t.associado_codigo = a.asscodass AND t.cartao_via = a.assultvia AND t.cartao_tipo = '0');
```

WITH fornece uma maneira de escrever subconsultas para uso em uma consulta SELECT maior. As subconsultas, que são muitas vezes referidos como expressões de tabelas comuns ou CTEs, pode ser pensado como a definição de tabelas temporárias que existem apenas para esta consulta. Um uso desse recurso é para quebrar consultas complicadas em partes mais simples.

Também, recomento a seguinte leitura[https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Dicas_de_Performance_em_aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es_com_PostgreSQL]